# Angular 2/4 - Handle parent component event in Directive

Tags: angular

I have the following scenario in an Angular 4 application:
i have a textbox and a span next to it.
The textbox is decorated with a directive that serves as an autocomplete directive. It shows up as a popup when a few characters are entered in the textbox.

I want that on click of the span element, the same popup should be shown (like a dropdown). For this, I planned to handle the (click) event of the span element and raise a custom event from the Component that hosts both the textbox and the span.

The question is how, will the autocomplete directive be able to listen to this event.
is this even a good approach. Are there any other approaches?